# TreeView Selected node

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Is there any chance to remove this dotted line around selected node ?

[image]

Comment: Which OS, and would you be okay with changing it to the Aero-style selection box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't remove it, this indicates the node with the focus and is necessary for users that select nodes with the keyboard.

If you want to throw this usability aspect out of the window then you can, TreeView supports custom drawing.  Set its DrawMode property to OwnerDrawText and implement an event handler for its DrawNode event.  Like:

```
private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) {
   Color back = e.Node.BackColor;
   Color fore = e.Node.ForeColor;
   if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) == TreeNodeStates.Selected) {
       back = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight);
       fore = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.HighlightText);
   }
   using (var br = new SolidBrush(back))
   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds);
   TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, e.Node.TreeView.Font, e.Bounds, fore);
}
```

Comment: It works, but when the control loses the focus, only text area remains hihglighted(I use .FullRowSelect = true). How can I change the code so full row becomes highlighted when the control loses the focus ?

Comment: I don't have a Windows version where that property still has an effect.  Windows 7 doesn't select the full row, only the text in the node, regardless of the property setting.  You're on your own to make it work on yours, sorry.  Don't get your hopes up to make that work btw, no way that it is going to let you draw over the connecting lines.

Comment: Btw, the screen shot doesn't look much like a full row select either.  Is this even real or are you jazzing me about pixels?

Comment: Windows 7 supports selection of the full row, [prooflink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.fullrowselect.aspx)

Comment: The FullRowSelect property is ignored if ShowLines is set to true

Answer (score -1):

Set the CSS as

```
outline: none;
```

which will remove dotted line.

### EDIT:

Apply css class something like this

```
<SelectedNodeStyle CssClass="selectNodeCSS" />
```

**OR**

```
<asp:TreeView ... SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="selectNodeCSS" ... />
```

*CSS:*

```
.selectNodeCSS {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Based on the post's tags, winform is in question here not css

Comment: @MPatel: Some portion of minor fixes can be done through CSS which is more easier to handle. So I feel it doesn't matter. If it is not tagged as CSS doesn't mean we shouldn't post. We should suggest best solution which is more feasible.

Comment: @Siva Charan: winforms doesn't use CSS at all. It's just old fashioned UI - no browser, no HTML, no CSS.

Comment: @Siva, could you provide code sample of how you plan to do that? I have go to see this to believe it.